# Django newbie trying to get treeio to work behind apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-python

I seem to have similar problem as this guy: [Django newbie deployment question - ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216340/django-newbie-deployment-question-importerror-could-not-import-settings-sett) but i cant make heads or tails of it.
The server is running Debian. The app runs fine on internal server, however when trying to use apache + mod_python i get the following problem.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

ImportError: Could not import settings 'treeio.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named treeio.settings
```

1. Project directory is /var/www/treeio
2. All files have file permission 777 (i was testing if there were any permission problems)
3. Content of httpd.conf

   ```
   <Location "/treeio/">
       SetHandler python-program
       PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
       SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE treeio.settings
       PythonOption django.root /treeio
       PythonDebug On
       PythonPath "['/var/www/treeio'] + sys.path"
   </Location>
   ```

More info:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
:/var/www/treeio/..:/var/www/treeio

echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
treeio.settings

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg', '/var/www/treeio', '/var/www', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6']
```

Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're using mod-python, despite clear warnings that it's deprecated and shouldn't be used for new projects.

But if you really insist on using it, the problem is quite clear: you're adding `/var/www/trio` to the path, so everything in `trio` needs to be referenced directly - `settings`, not `trio.settings`.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that. What would you recommend using instead of mod-python? Also: I've tried referencing only to settings (instead of treeio.settings) but it didnt work.

Comment: WSGI (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/) is a frequently used deployment strategy.

Comment: Doesnt look like treeio supports wsgi yet(?) atleast there's not any wsgi files in my project dir.

Comment: Correction, I added wsgi module, and also did the following: http://pastebin.com/DQKYbFKa But now i get a "Internal server error" :/

Comment: What's that `<files>` directive doing there? You don't need that.

Comment: Just tried to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ :) I removed the <files> stuff and still same thing.